# creating an association and scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I read "Multitenancy with Rails" by Ryan Bigg and I'm creating a multi-tenant application using Ruby on Rails.

I make two models, Tenant and User.
Tenant has many User, User belongs to Tenant.

To associate these models, I made this file,

active_record_extensions.rb

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.scoped_to_tenant
    belongs_to :tenant
    association_name = self.to_s.downcase.pluralize
    Tenant.has_many association_name.to_sym, class_name: self.to_s
  end
end
```

and add "scoped_to_tenant" to User.rb

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scoped_to_tenant
end
```

When I want to get all users of one Tenant(id=1), I can get it by these code.

```
Tenant.find(1).users
```

The question is, what is the difference between I write

```
belongs_to :tenant
```

to User.rb and use scoped_to_tenant method ?

In both case, Tenant.rb is this.

```rb
Tenant.rb < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end
```

Thank you for answer.
I may get English wrong, so please tell me if you can't understand something.

Comment: Maybe, these are same things and the reason to create scoped_to_tenant is just for using as a helper...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `scoped_to_tenant` method call the method `belongs_to` for you and add the many association to `Tenant`.

This is same as doing this :

```
# app/model/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
end

# app/model/tenant.rb
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

The benefit of the `scoped_to_tenant` is that you don't care about adding `has_many` relationship to `Tenant` model.
If you only have one model to associate with `Tenant`, you don't need this extension.